# при запуске программы выводиться только первое условие в любом случаи

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   int katet, gipotinuza, x;
katet=0;
gipotinuza=1;
cout<<"Что хотите найти КАТЕТ 
или ГИПОТЕНУЗУ?"<<endl;
cout<<"Если КАТЕТ вбейте число 
0"<<endl;
cout<<"Если 'ГИПОТЕНУЗА' вбейте 
число 1"<<endl;
cin>>x;

if(x=gipotinuza) {
    int a,b,d;
    cout<<"Введите первый катет - ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Введите тророй катет - ";
    cin>>b;
    d = sqrt(a*a+b*b);
    cout<<d<<endl;
}
else if (x=katet) {
    int a,b,d;
    cout<<"Введите гипотенузу - ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Введите катет - ";
    cin>>b;
    d = sqrt(a*a-b*b);
    cout<<d<<endl;

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1):

Все потому что вы не проверяете (оператор `==`) `x`, а присваиваете(оператор `=`).
Замените ваши `if` на эти:

```
if(x==gipotinuza) {
    //ваш код
}
else if (x==katet) {
//ваш код
}
```

Советы:

1. Не называйте имена траслитом, лучше перевести на англ. язык (`cathet` `hypotenuse`)
2. Называйте переменную зависимо от их "роли", ваш `x` уместно было бы назвать `choice`.